# How to delete image from folder

Tags: c#

When I upload new image, i want to delete previous uploaded image from folder.

Here is my code to upload an image :

```
try
{
      string filename = Image1.ImageUrl.Substring(Image1.ImageUrl.IndexOf('/', Image1.ImageUrl.Length));
      if (fileupload.PostedFile.FileName.Length > 0)
      {                        
             filename = Path.GetFileName(fileupload.PostedFile.FileName);
             fileupload.SaveAs(Server.MapPath("~/Images/" + filename));
      }                    
      com.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Image",(filename.Length>0)? "Images/" + filename:string.Empty);
      com.ExecuteNonQuery();                    
}
catch (Exception ex)
{
      btnsub.Text = ex.Message;
}
```

Here i am saving an image in a Server folder called **Images** using FileUpload, So before i upload a new image , i want to delete the previous uploaded image from the folder.

May I know, how to delete previous uploaded image?

Comment: the question is.do you have the name of the old image? as I guess you dont want to delete all previous files in the folder.

Comment: [File.Delete](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.file.delete%28v=vs.110%29.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396)?

Comment: Well ,you could easily list the images in the directory then first delete the previous then save your new coming Image . that much easy . Directory.GetFiles method helps listing them then  File.Delete(filePath); ...

Comment: Did you read the documentation that Default referenced? What is unclear to you? Please explain.

Comment: System.IO.File.Delete(imageName);

Comment: `File.Delete(path_to_previous_file);`? There are examples in the provided link. If you don't know how to use that, I am not sure how anyone is supposed to help you in a way that would be understandable.

Answer (score 12):

How to delete files

```
var filePath = Server.MapPath("~/Images/" + filename);
if(File.Exists(filePath))
{
    File.Delete(filePath);
}
```

How to delete all files in folder:

```
var folderPath = Server.MapPath("~/Images/");
System.IO.DirectoryInfo folderInfo = new DirectoryInfo(folderPath);

foreach (FileInfo file in folderInfo .GetFiles())
{
    file.Delete(); 
}
foreach (DirectoryInfo dir in folderInfo.GetDirectories())
{
    dir.Delete(true); 
}
```

Comment: `File.Delete` already checks for existence, so no need to check yourself.

Comment: where i can add your code in my code

Comment: I guess you should delete file before fileUpload.SaveAs()

Comment: i guess, on update right? but you told on insert.

Comment: `File.Delete` isn't recognized inside my actionResult. Is it required any library to add using?

Comment: @Cavid yes, using System.IO https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.io.file?view=netframework-4.8

Comment: using system.io not working, internal issue or has this changed @AccessDenied

Answer (score 0):

To delete all Server folder files

```
DirectoryInfo diInfo = new DirectoryInfo(Server.MapPath("foldername"));
FileInfo[] files = diInfo.GetFiles();
for (int i = 0; i < files.Length; i++)
{
  string filePath = Server.MapPath("~/foldername/" + files[i].ToString());
   if (File.Exists(filePath))
   {
      File.Delete(filePath);
   }
 }
```